# Best way to reach the tag I want in an XML file when it's repeated?

Tags: java, xml

first post in here. I have an XML file that includes the tag "usine" multiple times and I'm doing it in a way that does not seem right and I want to see if there's a more optimal way to do it. This is my first time working with XML and Node/NodeList so I'm still getting familiar with it.

Here is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<metadonnees>
    <usine type="usine-matiere">
        <icones>
            <icone type="vide" path="src/ressources/UMP0%.png"/>
            <icone type="un-tiers" path="src/ressources/UMP33%.png"/>
            <icone type="deux-tiers" path="src/ressources/UMP66%.png"/>
            <icone type="plein" path="src/ressources/UMP100%.png"/>
        </icones>
        <sortie type = "metal"/>
        <interval-production>100</interval-production>
    </usine>
    <usine type="usine-aile">
        <icones>
            <icone type="vide" path="src/ressources/UT0%.png"/>
            <icone type="un-tiers" path="src/ressources/UT33%.png"/>
            <icone type="deux-tiers" path="src/ressources/UT66%.png"/>
            <icone type="plein" path="src/ressources/UT100%.png"/>
        </icones>
        <entree type="metal" quantite="2"/>
        <sortie type="aile"/>
        <interval-production>50</interval-production>
    </usine>
</metadonnees>

<simulation>
    <usine type="usine-matiere" id="11" x="32" y="32"/>
    <usine type="usine-aile" id="21" x="320" y="32"/>
    <chemins>
        <chemin de="11" vers="21" />
        <chemin de="21" vers="41" />
    </chemins>
</simulation>
```

For example, if I want to retrieve the x value of 'usine type="usine-aile"' in the simulation tag, here is the code I use :

```
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("simulation");
        Node positionNode = nList.item(0);
        Element elementPosition = (Element) positionNode;

        NodeList cooList = elementPosition.getElementsByTagName("usine");
        Node cooNode = cooList.item(0);
        Element cooElem = (Element) cooNode;

        System.out.println(cooElem.getAttribute("x"));
```

Basically I have to make two NodeLists because the  I want is in the  tag and not the one in the  tag, so the first NodeList is to locate me in the  tag, then I go deeper making a new NodeList to find the  I want. Is there a better way to do this? I'm probably doing it a wrong way so I wish to know your answers. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, Get elements by tag name (e.g get elements of usine), it returns a `Nodelist` of that tag. e.g in `simulation` you have two `usine` tag(a `NodeList` with lenght of 2).

**Second**, you can iterate this `Nodelist` and do whatever you want to each node (element), for example you can get the attribute of each `usine` tag(
 `x` , `y`, `id`)

**In summary**

> 1- Get element by tag name (NodeList)
>
> 2- Iterate Nodelist
>
> 3- Process the nodes (e.g Get attribute of each node in the iteration process (`x`,`y`,`id`)

**I coded your scenario as follows**

```
public static void main(String argv[]) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {

        //Read xml file
        File fXmlFile = new File("/test.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        //Get usine nodes
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("usine");

        //Iterate nodeList
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nodeList.getLength(); temp++) {

            //Get each node and process it
            Node node = nodeList.item(temp);

            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                //Print attributes of the node
                Element element = (Element) node;
                System.out.println("X = " + element.getAttribute("x"));
                System.out.println("Y = " + element.getAttribute("y"));
                System.out.println("ID = " + element.getAttribute("id"));

            }
        }
    }
```

In this post, we're using `DOM Parser` for parsing XML, you can use this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-xml) to become more familiar with other XML processing libraries
like: **SAX Parser, StAX Parser and JAXB**,  these are much better than `DOM Parser` in terms of speed and performance.